# Use of TCP for real time small packet data over a period of time

Tags: android, python, sockets, tcp, real-time

I am pretty new to TCP networking and would like to use TCP for real time transfer of data.

Essentially, I need my PC python to send data (single character) to Android application. Data to be send changes in real time, and upon change to data (usually about 0.5 - 1sec apart), it has to send this new data to Android app and will be displayed on the app immediately.

My question is 
1) If I am using TCP, is it possible to keep the socket connection open even after sending one data to anticipate the subsequent transfers. Or do I need to close the connection after every single data transfer and set up another socket connection.

2) What is the latency of a TCP in the event I am performing something like these?

Any form of advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most TCP implementations delay sending small buffers for a short period of time (~.2 seconds) hoping that more data will be presented before adding the expense of sending the TCP segment. You can use the TCP_NODELAY option to (mostly) eliminate that delay. There are several other factors that get in the way, such as where the stack happens to be in an ACK sequence, but its reasonably good way to get prompt delivery.

Latency depends on many factors including other traffic on the line and whether a given segment is dropped and needs to be retransmitted. I'm not sure what a solid number would be.

Sometimes real time data is "better never than late", making UDP datagrams a good option.

*update*: A TCP connection stays open until you close them with shutdown(), a client or server level socket timeout hits or the underlying stack finally gets bored and closes it. So normally you just connect and send data periodically over time. A common way to deal with a timed out socket is to reconnect if you hit a send error.